# Programming to an interface or other abstract types

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstraction

In [a SO question on interface programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) a [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface#comment10126857_383982) says -

> Most answers to this question have the common misconception that
>   "programming to an interface" means use the interface language
>   construct; which is totally wrong! This is the first answer I've seen
>   that correctly illustrates that "programming to an interface" means:
>   don't unnecessarily bind your 'client code' to concrete/specific
>   subclass implementations because if you later decide to change it use
>   a different implementation, you have a lot more work undoing all the
>   unnecessary bindings. I.e. program to/bind to things without
>   implementation details. E.g. Abstract base classes.;)

Can some please expand on this point, preferably in relation to c#.

Comment: He's really just pointing out that other keywords (besides 'interface') provide polymorphism.  Its kind of a strawman that he's arguing against but w/e

Comment: When you declare an interface in c#, you specify **what** a class will do, rather than **how** it will do it.

By separating the how and the what, you make it a lot easier to replace the **how** later, whilst making sure that **what** your new module does stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation is that the answer is just expanding the notion of "interface" to mean binding to *any* set of properties and methods whether a "pure" interface (i.e. an `interface` in C#) or binding to a particular *implementation*.  The answer's point was that you *could* consider a class an "interface" by itself, and so you should program to the lowest base class that is necessary for your usage (a generic `List` contract versus a more specific `ArrayList` contract is that example).

You see this a lot in `System.IO` classes that bind to an abstract `TextReader` class versus an (non-existent) `ITextReader` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

If you have a method that makes an "animal" run in your mobile game, you can define a single 
`IAnimal` interface, and for every animal define its own run chinematics.

```
public interface IAnimal {
   Run(); 
}

public Dog : IAnimal{
   public void Run() {
       //DOG RUN CHINEMATICS
   }
}

public Elephant: IAnimal{
   public void Run() {
       //ELEPHANT RUN CHINEMATICS
   }
}
```

So you **hide** concrete implementation behind the `IAnimal` abstraction (its usually called contract for interfaces).

So during your physics engine run you can simply define **one** method:

```
public void RunAnimal(IAnimal animal) {
    animal.Run(); 
}
```

and call it like:

```
RunAnimal(new Dog());         //WILL CALL DOG CONCRETE METHOD
RunAnimal(new Elephant());    //WILL CALL ELEPHANT CONCRETE METHOD
```

So for `RunAnimal` method the *concrete impementation detail of animal* is hidden behind `IAnimal` "wall".

**EDIT**

So the answer to the question "why is programming to an interface not simply using the interface construct?" is:

An `interface` is and *instrument* which you can use to construct `interface` or `contract` based architecture. The same can be achieved simply by using `abstract base class`, or `simple base class` with `virtual methods`. So "programming to interface": is programming by having in mind to hide a concrete implementation detail from the consumer code (as much as it possible), to ensure maximum *maintanibility*, *flexibility* and *scallability* of your program. Use `interface`, `abstract class`, `base class`, whatever you want.

Comment: So how does this contrast with just having a base (abstract) `Animal` class?

Comment: @It does not *contrast* (in the meaning of that word in english), but just have different attributes. One of the most important  one is possibility of multiple inheritance in case of interfaces.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question is not *"what is programming to an interface?"*, but "*why is programming to an interface not simply using the **interface** construct?*"

Comment: @AlexanderR: Right, hence my comment on using an abstract base class, which can achieve the same aim, but with the restriction that you can do multiple inheritance (unless you have some horribly convoluted inheritance tree - an even then it's not quite the same thing). (BTW: I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 2):

1. With interface you have just signature of methods
2. With abstract class you can set common behavior of your child class, so write common code
3. multiple inheritance is impossible for C# so

you can implement multiple interfaces and not inherit multiple abstract class

1. When you create distribued component such as WCF Remoting etc.., you implement interface in order to communicate with your client.
2. You can use interface in order to tag a class

Comment: Sums up the few differences. Whether you use an interface or an abstract base class, you're still programming to an abstraction in that you're not coupled to any specific concrete implementation. The decision to use either one, or both, depends on the situation.

Comment: Thank's Ginosaji for complement, it depend of your case